# Compare rows in two columns according to conditions?

Tags: python, dataframe, rows

I have a data frame with two columns like this:

```
sap       years
a           10
a            5
b            0
c            0
```

and I want a function that has the following logic:

If two rows of sap have the same value (ex: a and a) AND if the same rows in years have different values (ex: 10 and 5), then change the row value to "Error"

This is how far it is probably not the right syntax for the logic:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('gg.xlsx')

groupby_df = df['years'].groupby(df['sap'])
for row in groupby_df:
    if row[0] != row[1]:
        print("found it")
```

I have tried duplicates, apply and shift and I couldn't think of a solution to this problem that compares the rows correctly.

Comment: What is the expected output? Should both rows having a be ERROR, or only one of them, if yes, which one of them?

Comment: only one of them, the row under the column "years"

Comment: Yes, but which one should be ERROR, the one with 10 or 5?

Comment: would it be possible change the lowest value to ERROR?

Comment: Great, happy to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, may be I would first check which rows from sap are duplicates, and which ones from sap + years are duplicates:

```
df['dup_sap'] = df.duplicated(['sap'], keep='first')
df['dup_sap_years'] = df.duplicated(['sap', 'years'], keep='first')
```

You will now have something like:

```
  sap  years  dup_sap  dup_sap_years
0   a     10    False          False
1   a      5     True          False
2   b      0    False          False
3   c      0    False          False
```

From the above, it is clear that there is a mismatch in the second row, so I would mark that as an error:

```
import numpy as np

df['Error_Flag'] = np.where((df.dup_sap == True) & (df.dup_sap_years == False), 'Yes', 'No')
```

Final output:

```
  sap  years  dup_sap  dup_sap_years Error_Flag
0   a     10    False          False         No
1   a      5     True          False        Yes   ##### this one marked as error
2   b      0    False          False         No
3   c      0    False          False         No
```

## Edit based on the comments:

For anyone who wants a solution where the ERROR mark must come on the lower value, here it is.

Take the minimum value per group like this:

```
minDf = df.groupby(['sap'])['years'].min().reset_index()
minDf['min_val'] = 1   # create a flag kind of a variable to denote this
```

Now merge them with the original dataframe and mark duplicates:

```
merge = pd.merge(df, minDf, on = ['sap', 'years'], how = 'left')
merge['dup_sap'] = df.duplicated(['sap'], keep=False)
merge['dup_sap_years'] = df.duplicated(['sap', 'years'], keep=False)
```

You should have a dataframe looking like:

```
  sap  years  min_val  dup_sap  dup_sap_years
0   a     10      NaN     True          False
1   a      5      1.0     True          False
2   b      0      1.0    False          False
3   c      0      1.0    False          False
```

Now create the condition to mark the error like this:

```
merge['Error_Flag'] = np.where((merge.dup_sap == True) & (merge.dup_sap_years == False) & (~merge.min_val.isna()), 'Yes', 'No')
```

Final output:

```
  sap  years  min_val  dup_sap  dup_sap_years Error_Flag
0   a     10      NaN     True          False         No
1   a      5      1.0     True          False        Yes
2   b      0      1.0    False          False         No
3   c      0      1.0    False          False         No
```

Hope this helps others.

Comment: it will not make lower year value to 'Error'. please clear the question and then improve the answer.

Comment: I completely agree with you. However, the OP seemed confused about which one to mark as error at first, hence I added this answer as it was simple. While she asked if lower value would be possible, she already saw this answer, marked it as accepted, and confirmed this already is good for her. Hence, I avoided further edits as the answer here is pertaining to her actual question and not doubtful discussions in the comments. :) Should she require it compulsorily based on minimum value, I shall edit it then :)